# CRUD operations in wordpress

Tags: custom-post-types, api

Recently volunteered (for a friend) to make a website for his business with same added features. I do have moderate web-dev experience but really wanted to try to use wordpress for this. Here are some of the features i am looking for, (will try to be as brief as possible).

1. Ability to create custom objects with custom fields (e.g. Orders). Then 
   basically having some sort of ability to perform CRUD operations on the 
   same. Field could also be of type image/images, where the user gets an option to upload picture for that field.
2. Ability to create fields on other entities of another type (e.g.
   Order object will have a field of type Customer)
3. Expose APIs that allow us to change certain fields (for e.g. simple
   /GET api which changes a boolean status) No requirement for
   authentication and all that.
   http://www.website.com/api/changeorder?status=pending

Would be great to get some feedback on above.

Comment: for 1. et 2. you can use custom post types, it's like new objects : https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type. and for 3. look this : https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/

Comment: if you want more details, it's better to create a different question for each part, this will be easier for people which want to help you.

Answer (score 1):

All of your requirements can be achieved with Wordpress either through the use of plugins and/or the development of custom code.

If you are not familiar with Wordpress development, then you may find the learning curve to be quite steep at first even if you have good web-development knowledge. However if you have a bit of time, then you will find that Wordpress is a good platform on which to develop. Otherwise, if you do not want to develop custom code, you will find the range of available free and paid for plugins if quite comprehensive and you are almost certain to find solutions that meet your needs.

A final point worth making is that Wordpress would be a good choice because it is very well supported and will meet your CRUD requirements with a bit of configuration.

It is difficult to advise further without knowing your specific requirements.

Answer (score 1):

All those 3 requirements are really possible on WordPress.

For question no 1, you can use Custom Post Type (CPT). Most of "custom object” on WordPress are used as CPT. As CPT, you can easily do CRUD and other actions using WordPress API and predefined functions. You can also use custom table, means you create your own custom table on database, then use WordPress API for custom table. In my experiences, most of object i needed sufficient enough to use CPT.

For question no 2, in WordPress, there is thing called MetaBox. MetaBox are custom field using for enhancing default WordPress Post or Custom Post Type.

If you ever known about WooCommerce, they use CPT for saving “object” like Products, and Orders. CPT will help it to save the title, description, and helping access them easily with WordPress API. But to save more data like pricing, variation of products (like color, weight, size etc), order status, customer information they use custom MetaBox.

For question no 3, of course you can do that. You can accept GET and POST request on your theme, or plugin, it’s all PHP after all. You can always treat it as usual.

Just little suggestion, avoid to use GET request to make changes to database record.